can't Import firebase_options.dart
I can't Import firebase_options.dart to the main.dart file. And I also got this Error:

FirebaseCommandException: An error occured on the Firebase CLI when attempting to run a command.
COMMAND: firebase apps:create android thrive (android) --package-name= --json --project=thrive-d0452
ERROR: Package name for Android app cannot be empty

But I downloaded the cli and also activated firebase.
Can someone help me?

It looks like the package name is not being passed along to the CLI.
In cases where I've had this, I was able to solve it by specifying the Android package name directly in the CLI call rather than waiting for the prompt. For an example of this, see the documentation:
flutterfire configure --platforms=android --android-package-name=your.application.id

